# React - loading Lightbox component into another component

Tags: reactjs

I found a React [lightbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lr3q9qlw9m). I am trying to make slight modifications to it and one of those modifications is that I want to include it in another component. I attempted to do that by changing `render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));` to `export default App` and then importing it into my component. But when I do that I get `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` Here's how I am importing it:

```
import React from "react";
import LB from "./LB";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return <LB />;
}
```

[Here's my attempt](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-moon-5bt16)

Comment: Why don't you just import the lightbox into the component where you want to use it?

Comment: @i.brod I tried that, but the component where I want to use it is set up the same way(as an export) so I end up running into the same issue.

Comment: I don't really understand..can you upload your code?

Comment: I mean, i understand that this is just some example you took from

Comment: @i.brod the link at the bottom of the question is my attempt at converting it to an export. For some reason when I handle it this way I get the error listed above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
        <div onClick={this.openLightbox}>Click Me</div>
        <Lightbox
          views={photos}
          onClose={this.closeLightbox}
          onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
          onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
          currentImage={this.state.currentImage}
          isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
        />
      </div>
```

You were passing incorrect prop. Never rely on some dubious examples, always refer to the docs. "images" should be "views"

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I wonder why it was working in the person's example using that prop, they must have remapped it or something? Sorry, I am quite new to React, I will definitely check out the docs first next time!

Comment: Yes it's really weird, but this isn't the first time i see broken examples...maybe the version is different or something